# What is the name for the inverse of an aphorism

Tags: word-order, aphorism, antonyms

For example, given a common saying or sequence of words, like

> A picture is worth a thousand words

One reverses the order and obtains

> A word is worth a thousand pictures

Is there a name for this kind of wordplay/whatever it is? I seem to hear them all the time, I can give more examples if needed.

Comment: Ronald, quoting from your question "A word is worth a thousand pictures" is not common usage, but in situations where using "A word is worth a thousand pictures" can sound brilliant, using it is not restricted, but I do not seem to recall any specific terminology describing what you have questioned about because it is not common usage. More examples would be helpful.

Comment: A word is *not* worth a thousand pictures.

Comment: @Luke Not even "**Polaroid**"?

Comment: @Luke: What if [the word is "Om"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_(The_Moody_Blues_song))? Or if it's [the word that became flesh](http://biblia.com/bible/esv/Jn1.14)?

Comment: I suppose I'll recant that... Polaroid. LOL

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An inversion such as "a word is worth a thousand pictures" is described as an ***implied chiasmus*** by Wordsmith.org founder, [Anu Garg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anu_garg), [here](http://wordsmith.org/words/chiasmus.html), quoting these immortal words of Kermit the Frog:

> Time's fun when you're having flies.

A [chiasmus](http://wordsmith.org/words/chiasmus.html) is "a rhetorical inversion of the second of two parallel structures." In the link, which is well worth reading, the examples of the inversion are of the sort: "Ask not what your country can do for you; ask what you can do for your country." So the *implied chiasmus* would be simply the second part, where the first (unspoken) one is the better known aphorism ("time flies when you're having fun" or "a picture is worth a thousand words").

Comment: Frankly dam, I don't give a deer!

Comment: Excellent link. The word's a new one on me - but examples certainly abound, so that's a handy addition to my lexicon, thanks!

Comment: +1 great answer. I suspect the kind of straight inversion in the OP's example is at best a special sub-set of (implied) *chiasmus*.

Answer (score 8):

If

> Screaming: Words speak louder than actions ("Actions speak louder than words")

is a structure that imitates OP's example of "A word is worth a thousand pictures", then it is a

[Transpositional pun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpositional_pun) (Wikipedia)

> a complicated pun format with two aspects. It involves transposing the words in a well-known phrase or saying to get a daffynition-like clever redefinition of a well-known word unrelated to the original phrase. The redefinition is thus the first aspect, the transposition the second aspect.

"A hard man is good to find." - Mae West
"No Left Turn Unstoned"

TP on UNCF's motto, "A Mind is a Terrible Thing to Waste."

[image]
<sub>(source: [wasteisaterriblethingtomind.com](http://wasteisaterriblethingtomind.com/images/bookcover_trans.gif))</sub>

<sup>http://wasteisaterriblethingtomind.com/</sup>

Comment: No down vote, but the changing in meaning of one of the words required by the pun seems to discount this as an answer.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Change in meaning is not a requirement, according to the definition above. Is there another definition of TP that you know of?

Comment: How is it not a requirement when; "**The redefinition is thus the first aspect**"?(emphasis mine)

Comment: @JoshuaDrake *waste* (*v* use or expend carelessly, extravagantly, or to no purpose); *waste* (*n* refuse, garbage, trash) -- *mind* (*n* the faculty of consciousness); *mind* (*v* care, pay attention). Make an effort before reaching for conclusions :)

Comment: That is a redefinition of terms as used in the original. Where as in the OPs question no redefinition occurs. As I said, no down vote, as the idea is related, but not identical. :P

Comment: @JoshuaDrake "That is a redefinition" -- don't be in a hurry :) the redefinition comes by virtue of the context. OP's sentence is free of context for the purpose of the question. See Wiki link where the examples are listed **with context**. The *transposition* part is in the sentence/ phrase; the *pun* part of it comes from the context with a clever use.

Comment: Joshua Drake has the high ground in this argument, but I share his implicit gratitude (no down vote) to Kris for having brought our attention to the transpositional pun as a close cousin of the implied chiasmus that provoked the OP's post.